Unreachable java.lang.ClassValue$ClassValueMap objects not cleaned by GC
We have an enterprise application deployed on Wildfly. Java version used to run is 11.0.22+7-LTS.
We see a weird problem in perform env. Every time we collect a live heapdump, we see a bulk of memory is  retained by “java.lang.ClassValue$ClassValueMap” objects even though it is unreachable.
When we import the heap dump into MAT, it clearly shows "Unreachable". Unreachable and Leak Suspect
Yet the GIGC is not clearing up the space
For collecting heap dump we use the command JAVA_HOME/bin/jmap -dump:live,file=/opt/smp/heap.hprof <pid>
the JVM argumennts we use are
-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGC -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=33554432 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xlog:gc*:file=/log/gc.log:time:filecount=5,filesize=3m -XX:HeapDumpPath=/log/heapDump.hprof -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhazelcast.health.monitoring.level=OFF -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=999999 -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/smp20/belsmp02_8404 -Djboss.node.name=belsmp02_7404 -Djgroups.bind_addr=10.xxx.xx.xxx -Djgroups.tcp.address=10.xxx.xx.xxx -Dsmp.database.type=oracle -Djboss.server.log.dir=/log -Djboss.server.temp.dir=/tmp -Djboss.server.data.dir=/data -Dlogging.configuration=file:/data/logging.properties
In production, OOM heap dump also have same problem. java.lang.ClassValue$ClassValueMap are retained and not cleaned up by GC.
Any pointer when this could happen? What next we can try out?
We tried increasing the G1HeapRegionSize. This did not help. We also have not configured aby time limit for GC to complete.

It turned out to be a bug in dynalink module of jdk. https://github.com/szegedi/dynalink/issues/15

It is considered best practice on StackOverflow to create your own Answer and mark as Accepted if your issue is solved.

It turned out to be a bug in dynalink module of jdk. This issue - https://github.com/szegedi/dynalink/issues/15 was the root cause of my problem.
